# Why redis is not storing data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

i am trying to set and get cache data from redis but when I hit the API its just loading and loading and not giving any error or response what can be the issue with my redis and my nodejs API? i am using the latest version of redis how can I make things works?

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient({
    url: 'redis://default:mypass@redis-16246.c81.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:16246'
});

client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

router.post("/getuserwithpet", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email } = req.body;

        // Try to retrieve data from cache
        client.get(email, async (err, cachedData) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (cachedData) {
                // If cached data is still valid, return it
                const now = new Date();
                const expiration = new Date(JSON.parse(cachedData).expiration);
                if (expiration > now) {
                    return res.json(JSON.parse(cachedData).data);
                }
            }

            const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
            let pet = user.pet;

            const count = await User.countDocuments({ pet: pet });
            if (count === 0) {
                return res.status(404).json({ error: "No users found with that pet" });
            }

            let dataToCache;

            if (cachedData && JSON.parse(cachedData).data) {
                dataToCache = JSON.parse(cachedData).data;
            } else {
                dataToCache = await User.aggregate([
                    { $match: { pet: pet, email: { $ne: email } }, },
                    { $sample: { size: 1, }, },
                    { $project: { name: 1, username: 1, profileImg: 1 } },
                ]);
            }

            const now = new Date();
            const expiration = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 5, 0, 0, 0);
            const dataToCacheWithExpiration = { data: dataToCache, expiration: expiration };
            client.set(email, JSON.stringify(dataToCacheWithExpiration));
            res.json(dataToCache);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest (v4 and up) node-redis client uses Promises not callbacks, so try refactoring:

```js
client.get(email, async (err, cachedData) => {
  ...
}
```

To something like:

```js
try {
  const cachedData = await client.get(email);
  //  your logic here
} catch (e) {
  // something went wrong...
}
```